# How to search for emails sent by a specific person in iOS Mail

Tags: email, ios, search

I used to be able to search for emails sent by "Jack Tan" by using the FROM toolbar in the mailbox

[image]

After iOS 7 update, it seems the From, All, Subject, and To toolbar has disappeared. It now looks like this when i attempt to search (red bar to indicate the toolbar is gone)

[image]

This has not allowed me to search for a specific sender in my Mail. When I attempt to search in my Mail for (e.g. "Jack Tan"), the results will be emails whose content contains "Jack Tan".

**I want to be able to search for emails sent by "Jack Tan"**

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately Apple has removed this in iOS7.
Please also check out [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5323188?tstart=0) about the issue you described.

If you really *need* this function right away you have to check for 3rd party apps.

Edit:Some people claim typing; **from:**  will result in the search you like, but it does not work for me.

Comment: Typing "from :" does not work for me also

Answer (score 1):

You could add "Jack Tan" to the VIP list (at least temporary): it is not a proper solution, but it could help you to locate the messages.

Comment: Would do as workaround I guess, not ideal.